# MongoDB Max Connections

Tags: php, centos6, mongodb

we are using mongodb in our application for catching a lot of the data to reduce load from our main mysql database, for the last 2 3 days we are having an issue where the mongodb will hit the limit and will not accept anymore connections, hence stalling our whole application, we have a fairly large server with 32GB of Ram and 12 Core Processor, when I run

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

It returns

> {
>           "current" : 1011,
>           "available" : 50189,
>           "totalCreated" : NumberLong(159685)
>   }

My question is, why it only accepta 1011 connections and start rejecting others even though it has 50189 available connections? Or how can we increase that limit?

The logs say

> 2014-07-10T03:04:30.394-0400 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
>   2014-07-10T03:04:30.399-0400 Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:27017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
>   exception: connect failed

Thanks

Comment: What appears in the logs when mongodb refuses connections?

Comment: @Flup, I have edited the answer.

Comment: Can you comment on the version you are using - the treatment of max connections changed with 2.6

Comment: this output looks like version 2.6.  however, it's not clear to me that you've run out of connections - this looks like an error caused by the shell not being able to connect to the server, not from the server giving an error because it cannot create/accept another connection.  If you've run out of connections, there would be lots of errors in mongod log file of the sort "cannot create connection" or pthread no resources or some such.   Are you sure it's mongod that's not accepting more connections? Rather than the network/machine?

Comment: wasn't it maybe the open files limit? think it's around 1000 by default